# OrientDB: avoid returning to the same node in OSql query

Tags: orientdb

O.!
I'm trying to write an `in().out()` query in OSql but I would like to avoid coming back to the starting node, for example in the graph `e0 <- c0 -> e1` I would like to go from `e0` to `e1` and not from `e0` to `e0` again. 
Notice that I don't know the RID of the target node and there could be more than one node connected to `c0` that I would like to include in my result set.

I've tried many variants of the following query without success.

```
SELECT $other
FROM Employee 
LET $other = (
    SELECT in('Involves').out('Involves').email as mail 
    FROM $parent.$current 
    WHERE $current <> $parent.$current)
WHERE nt_account = 'e0'
```

Does anybody have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
    SELECT $other.mail
    FROM Employee 
    LET $other = ( select from (SELECT in('Involves').out('Involves').email as mail FROM $parent.$current unwind mail) where name<>$parent.$current.email )
```